# Write formatted text to file - C++

Tags: c++, io

I have this code:

```
        printf("GPU: %ic  SYSTEM: %ic  CPU: %ic  HDD: %ic  ",temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[7]);
        ofstream temp_file;
        temp_file.open("D:\\localhost\\xampp\\htdocs\\monitor\\temps.json");
        temp_file << fprintf("\"{\"GPU\": [%ic], \"System\": [%ic], \"CPU\": [%ic], \"HDD\": [%ic]}\"", temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[7]);
        temp_file.flush();
        temp_file.close();
```

and I get the error "cannot convert 'const char*' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' for argument '1' to 'int fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)'

the temp variable is an int, and the first line of the code does successfully print out the formatted text. How do i push that text to a file?

Comment: Why not use `FILE*` and `fopen()` if they are easy to use for you?

Comment: What you want to use may be [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Comment: Check the arguments taken by fprintf. Compare to your code. Read the error message again. Also, avoid the legacy C functions like printf, because they are not type safe and it's extremely easy to create undefined behavior bugs. Just use C++ streams.

Comment: Regrading error it is clear - you do call `fprintf()` with 1st argument being `const char*` instead of `FILE*` in the 4th line f your code - `fprintf("\"{\"GPU...`. Regarding your 2nd question _"How do i push that text to a file"_ - use your `ofstream temp_file` but read docs and samples how to use stl streams. That's me who downvoted this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `fprintf()`.

`fprintf()` returns an `int` and expects its first argument to be a `FILE *`, [per the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html):

```
int fprintf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

You need to format your text first using `s[n]printf()` if that's the route you want to take - making a C-style string and writing it to a C++ `ofstream`:

```
char buffer[ BUF_SIZE ];
snprintf( buffer, sizeof( buffer ),
    "\"{\"GPU\": [%ic], \"System\": [%ic], \"CPU\": [%ic], \"HDD\": [%ic]}\"",
    temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[7] );

...

temp_file << buffer;

...
```

There are many other ways to format output in C++, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `boost::format`:

```
cout << boost::format("\"{\"GPU\": [%1%], \"System\": [%2%], \"CPU\": [%3%], \"HDD\": [%4%]}\"") % temp[0] % temp[1] % temp[2] % temp[3];
```

Comment: Boost overkill for this, like using a jackhammer to get the shell off a peanut.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, without knowing the scope of the problem, it's really difficult to comment and these days is it really that difficult to pull in boost?

Comment: Without knowing the scope of the problem, recommending Boost is even more overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This `temp_file << fprintf("\"{\"GPU\": [%ic], \"System\": [%ic], \"CPU\": [%ic], \"HDD\": [%ic]}\"", temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[7]);` is wrong. You cannot combine `ofstream` and `fprintf` - use one or the other.

To write formatted output to a stream you use [io manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) and you don't need to do anything special to output integers, strings, doubles etc.

Comment: _"You cannot combine ofstream and fprintf"_ Strictly speaking this is wrong statement. Why not? Just do it right way. Why to do it and what to do instead - subjects of a different discussions

Comment: The `fprintf` returns the number of characters written.  The statement is outputting the number of characters printed, so yes, `fprintf` can be used with the stream insertion operator.

Comment: Yes, yes, but not in the way the OP intended, which I'm sure you guys know perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of fprintf must be the pointer to a FILE object that identifies the stream instead of temp[0] (GPU).

The C library function int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...) sends formatted output to a stream.